# Setting WPF RepeatBehavior to "none" in VB.net Code Behind

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How do I set the repeatbehavior of a WPF 4 mediatimeline in VB.net 2010 code behind?

I know the following code sets the repeatbehavior to forever:

```
MyMediaTimeline.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
```

However, there doesn't seem to be anything preset for setting the repeat behavior to none. I'm guessing I'll need to do something like the following, but what should the "?" be?

```
MyMediaTimeline.RepeatBehavior = New RepeatBehavior(?)
```

As a side note, I have the following above the class.

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the default behaviour (play once), you just have to set the RepeatBehavior to 1 ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.repeatbehavior.aspx))

`MyMediaTimeline.RepeatBehavior = New RepeatBehavior(1)`

Answer (score -1):

MyMediaTimeline.RepeatBehavior = New RepeatBehavior(1)

Comment: A RepeatBehavior of 0 will result in not playing the animation at all